# Transfer a modified sharepoint Excel file to another folder

Tags: azure, sharepoint, power-automate, power-platform

Is there a way that whenever I modify an Excel file in sharepoint in the "INPUT" folder the file is then copied to the "OUTPUT" folder erasing the previous one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the tag [flow] in your question, so I'll answer with that.

This is a straight forward flow to create. You need two steps

- The trigger is a Sharepoint one - `When a file is created or modified in a folder`. You provide the site name and the source folder
- The next action is a Sharepoint `Move file`.

  - Current Site address is the same as the trigger
  - File to move is the Dynamic Content `x-ms-file-id`
  - Destination Site is the site where you want to copy the file to
  - Destination folder is the target folder
  - Choose your overwrite strategy, presumably 'Replace'

[image]

Comment: Hello, I used to copy file action since I want to keep the file in my input folder. The problem is that while I am modifying the file it gets copied after each modification. Isn't there a way to tell it to copy the file only after I'm done with the modifications ?

Comment: It would have no way to know what you mean by 'done' without some sort of human interaction. Consider adding another action into your flow, possibly an Approval one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/approvals/